# basic authentication not working in eclipse but works when i put my app in web-app in apache-tomcat

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

i am facing a problem in using basic authentication.. 
initially i tried this in eclipse but i got 404 error, i tried everything, restarting, creating new projects but nothing worked. 
then i exported the war file n deployed it in apache-tomcat web-app folder and started tomcat from command line and it worked,, 
when i go this way i get the expected output when i refresh the page in eclipse , it works. 
but then again of i run shutdown.bat and run server in eclipse and again refresh the page.. I GET NOTHING.. SAME 404 ERROR 
please help

Comment: are you able to see successful startup message for tomcat in eclipse?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar yes, i am able to get successful startup message and no severe error for my project too.

Answer (score 0):

Check properly that may be you deployed your .jsp file inside WEB-INF folder so you will get this error because WEB-INF is secure.So create .jsp .html inside web-content.
Error 404 means your tomcat not able to get requested resource.

You can go here and check here 
[DeployentStructure](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html)

Comment: [@Prasad Kharkar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1727645/prasad-kharkar) I think he is providing his resource under different directory.

Comment: there is no problem in deploying the structure. when i remove authentication everything is working fine, as soon as i add the authentication error 404